# Imputation of missing value in LDA

Tags: r, r-caret, imputation, r-mice

I want to present PCA & LDA plots from my results, based on 140 inviduals distributed according one categorical variable. In this individuals I have measured 50 variables (gene expression). For PCA there is an specific package called missMDA to perform an imputation process in the dataset

I want to perform LDA and see how the 3 groups or clusters behave across all variables however in LDA I am a little bit overwhelmed with all the possible combinations (knn.impute, preProcess..) I'm doubting between several options:

preProcess from the caret package, which seems to be used in this context.I don't know which method to pick, knnImpute/center/scale or a combination of them? If I pick k-nearest neighbors, I don't know if default value = 5 is the correct choice
mice function to perform imputation on the dataframe using the "cart" method, which is suitable for mixed data
Is there any specific approach to imputation My data is normal

Thanks in advance